# Embedding a form without breaking built in rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a reusable comment resource that I can add to other resources so that they can have comments. I can achieve this relatively easily using the following:

IE: views/blog/index.html.erb

```
# blog here...
<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { comment: Comment.new } %>
<%= render @comments %>
```

controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }       
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
...
```

views/comment/_form.html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: comment, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_area :message, rows: 5 %>
  <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-secondary float-right' %>
<% end %>
```

This works however the form validation does not work no matter how I configure the form.

Ways I have tried to configure the form:

Solution 1

```
<%= form_with(model: comment, local: false) do |form| %>
```

This solution works however the native rails form validation breaks and it won't display validation errors.

Solution 2

```
<%= form_with(model: comment, format: 'json') do |form| %>
```

Once again form validation doesn't work and would require me to wire this up myself in javascript (I would rather use rails out of the box functionality)

Solution 3:

```
<%= form_with(model: comment, local: true) do |form| %>
```

This works however it redirects me off the original page and onto /comments/new when there is a validation issue (and successfully validates it there).

I find a lot of benefit in doing things the "rails way". My question is what is the official rails way for embedding a form for a resource in a different resources view and still getting the nice built in rails validation?

What is the official rails way to handle this?

Comment: Please, add the `create` method code. Also, I guess when you say `views/comment/_comment.html.erb` you actually mean `views/comments/_form.html.erb`. Don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation for `local:true` mode does not work because you are passing a new empty object to the form every time. You need to pass an object that has just failed to save (and thus has `errors` set).

'Rails-way' is simple CRUD, where you have form rendered and processed by the same controller, and once you already breaking it with shared form (your comments controller obviously does not know how to render the page form was originally on), I'd do it in javascript (or with remote form).

For the latter - make sure you render error messages appropriately in comment `create` action

Answer (score 0):

As @Vasfed says, you are breaking the *Rails-way*, so you need more work on your controller:

```rb
def index
  @comment = Comment.new # You need this to remove it from the partial render
  @comments = Comments.all
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }       
    else
      format.html do
        @comments = Comments.all # DRY this with a private method and use it in index
        render :index
      end
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

In your view you don't need to set `locals[:comment]` since you can use `@comment` right in the form, but you can keep it if you want:

```rb
<%= render 'comments/form', comment: @comment %>
<%= render @comments %>
```

I'm sorry if I (likely) forget something. I didn't test it.